# I want to display Images present in model in different divs in razor view asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have send images from actioncontroller to view and now i am applying foreach loop but it's displaying all of images in one place whereas i want to display first image at first div and second in second etc.

here's my action:

```
  public ActionResult show_pics2()
        {
            DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            List<byte[]> images = (from f in db.Images                                 
                                   select f.ImageContent).ToList();
            return View(images);
        }
```

Here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<byte[]>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Portfolio";
}

@{ var imgsrc="";}
@{ int i = 0;
     }


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                // converting to string
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item);
                imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            }
        }
```

Please tell me a way to display images in different divs through foreach loop.

Like

```
<div class="grid"> 
    <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x857"> /* I want to display first image from db here******/ </div> 
    <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x1280"> /* I want to display second image from db here ****/ </div>
    <div class="description description--grid"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the `<div>` that should warp the `<img>` inside the loop:

```
<div class="grid">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        // converting to string
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item);
        imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
        <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x857">
            <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
         </div>
    }
    <div class="description description--grid"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But its giving me error, i am using @model IEnumerable<byte[]> and you're asking me to Model.Length which is giving me error.

Comment: Change `Length` to `Count()` (using System.Linq).

Comment: Done but in var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j]); i am sending an image

Comment: And in loop its sending an integer, can u please tell me how to add image in this loop? not model[j] ? but model[item] where item is byte[] image

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken that @model is an array, but it is IEnumerable. Either use the original foreach loop or acces the current item using `ElementAt()`.

Comment: But how to display images in different divs using foreach loop?

Comment: I am not very clear on what you mean by "in different divs". This code will render a `<div>` around each `<img>`. Please expand your question to show your desired output!

Comment: I have retrieved images from db and sent to view .. the model contains 9 images which i want to display in different places on web

Comment: Like         
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x857">
                    // I want to display first image from db here******
                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x1280">
                  //I want to display second image from db here ****
                        <div class="description description--grid">
                          
                        </div>

Comment: That is in different divs but with foreach displays all images in db but i want to display one image in one div and another in other one . Please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old but maybe it can still be helpful for someone.

here is what i did!

Instead of setting the image tag in the foreach loop,

set a `new List`

and add the image src to the new `List` like this

```
//This is the new list
List<string> images = new List<string>(); //it must be initialized before use

@foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                // converting to string
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item);
                imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                images.Add(imgsrc);
            }
        }
```

Then you can use it however you want and display it where you want.

```
<div class="grid"> 
    <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x857"> 
        <img src="@images[0]" alt="sample" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x1280"> 
        <img src="@images[1]" alt="sample" />
    </div>
    <div class="description description--grid"> 
</div>
```